# @ManagedProperty Does not fill in the variable

Tags: java, spring, primefaces

In the applicationContext file I have added the package to map it.
The call arrives, but the variable is still null and does not pass to the server. In other classes, the same is working correctly.

Thanks in advance!

```
@ManagedBean(name="registerUser")
@SessionScoped
public class RegisterUser{

    @ManagedProperty("#{userService}")
    private DAOUser userService;

    private User user = new User();

    public DAOUser getUserService() {
        return userService;
    }

    public void setUserService(DAOUser userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public String register() {
        // Calling Business Service
        String passwordEncripada = PasswordControl.encriptString(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncripada);
        userService.register(user);
        // Add message
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, 
                new FacesMessage("Registro realizado"));
        return "";
    }
```

and DAOUser class:

```
@Component
public class DAOUser implements Serializable {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    @Transactional
    public void register(User user){
        // Acquire session
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        // Save employee, saving behavior get done in a transactional manner
        session.save(user);     
    }
}
```

EDIT: The setter is called, but the object it sends is null

Comment: if you ask the question in english , Many people can understand and chances of getting solution could be high.

Comment: Maybe a wrong import - for example of SessionScoped?

Comment: i'm using : 
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was in the normalization of the DAOUser class name. I have gone to use @Repository ("userService") instead of @Component and it is already working.

```
@Repository("userService")
public class DAOUser implements Serializable {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    @Transactional
    public void register(User user){
        // Acquire session
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        // Save employee, saving behavior get done in a transactional manner
        session.save(user);     
    }
}
```